# Method to check higher precendence of operators, Is there a smarter way to do this?

Tags: java, math, operators, switch-statement

Here's a method I wrote to check which operator has the highest precedence, now my question is: is there any other way I can do this? I have been testing this one and it works fine, but I'm pretty sure there should be room for improvement. What do you think?

```
static boolean hasHigherPrecendence(char top, char current){

    String t = String.valueOf(top);
    String c = String.valueOf(current);

    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(c);

    switch (t) {
    case "-":
        if ( c.equals("-") || c.equals("+") )
            return false;
        break;      
    case "+":
        if ( c.equals("-") || c.equals("+") )
            return false;
        break;          
    case "/":
        if ( !c.equals("*") || !c.equals(t) || !c.equals("%") )
            return false;
        break;      
    case "*":
        if ( !c.equals("%") || !c.equals(t) || !c.equals("/"))
            return false;
        break;
    case "%":
        if (c.equals(t) || c.equals("*") || c.equals("/"))
            return false;
        break;          
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator unknown: " + t);
    }       

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why change a `char` into a `String` if you don't need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it were me I would rank the operators in a function (note, the values I chose are not necessarily the ones you should use ...):

```
private static final int rankOperator(char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '-' : return 0;
        case '+' : return 0;
        case '/' : return 2;
        case '*' : return 2;
        case '%' : return 4;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown operator " + op);
}


public boolean hasHigherPrecedence(char top, char current) {
    return rankOperator(top) > rankOperator(current);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can choose my own values as long as they represent the precedence in a correct order, I like your approach better. Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

```
static boolean hasHigherPrecendence(char top, char current){
    Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('+',new Integer(1));
    map.put('-',new Integer(1));
    map.put('*',new Integer(2));
    map.put('/',new Integer(2));
    map.put('%',new Integer(3));
    if( map.get(top)==null ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator unknown: " + top);
    }
    if( map.get(current)==null ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator unknown: " + current);
    }
    if(map.get(t) >= map.get(c)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart of using maps, arrays, functions... you can reduce your code using the concatenating the cases with the same behaviour:

```
static boolean hasHigherPrecendence(char top, char current){

    String t = String.valueOf(top);
    String c = String.valueOf(current);

    System.out.println(t);
    System.out.println(c);

    switch (t) {
    case "-":
    case "+": 
        if ( c.equals("-") || c.equals("+") )
            return false;
        break;              
    case "/": 
    case "*":
    case "%":
        if (c.equals("%") || c.equals("*") || c.equals("/"))
            return false;
        break;          
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator unknown: " + t);
    }       

    return true;
}
```